# Unable to Hide content on click print button jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I would like to hide the content of the page whenever i click on **button print** of **jQuery Datatable**.
The default behaviour is that the main window is displayed in the background and the print preview is displayed on Modal pop up!

Here is what i have tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Data Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.1.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tdbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                    <td>Team Leader</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2008/10/26</td>
                    <td>$235,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/03/09</td>
                    <td>$324,050</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
            </tdbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.1.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        {
          extend: 'print',
          customize: function(win) {
            $(win.document.body).css( 'opacity', '0' )
                        
 
            $(win.document.body).find('print-preview-app').css('opacity', '1' );

          }
        }
          
      ]
  });
});
```

Here is the output whenever i click on Print button!
As you can see the modal has no table on
[image]

Here is the fiddle of what i have tried [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kanachrisi/n1kc9dyt/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hiding the wrong thing.

**`win` argument to the `customize` function is the popup window - don't hide that one! Hide the main window!**

So you have two things:

- `win`: that is the popup window. (Also not sure if you get access to jQuery there, try it first).
- `window`: is your main window.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/h8sqyf5p/2/) is a working example: print preview popup is showing the table, but the main window is hiding the contents. I also added code to bring back the opacity on the main window, when you close the print preview.

```
customize: function(win) {
  console.log('Hiding the main window.');
  $(window.document.body).css( 'opacity', '0' )
  // Just to make sure, change something in the popup window
  win.document.body.querySelector('table').style.border = '2px dotted tomato';
  // ALSO make sure that we bring back the main window opacity.
  win.onbeforeunload = () => {
          console.log('Before unload, return .')
          $(window.document.body).css('opacity', 1);
        }

      }
```

---

Edit: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pcabsd87/4/) what you want? You want to hide the table in the *popup* window, but visible in the print?

You can do that as well, with a media query:

```
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = `
@media screen {
    table {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@media print {
    table {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
`;
win.document.body.appendChild(style);
```

The `media screen { }` rule will match only for "screen" view - a normal browser window, while with `media print {}` you can create css rules that will only be valid on the printed page.

Comment: Hello ! The main window is still displayed with a red dotted line, check again your code!

Comment: What do you call the "main window" - the one with the print button, or the popup window? Also, the red-dotted line is how I showed you how to paint the popup window.

Comment: With the new modification the table in popup window is hidden, but visible in the print preview. There is only one thing is that the title of DataTable still visible in popup window

Comment: Yes, that is on purpose. You're not supposed to blindly copy-paste code from here until it works - can you figure out what is yet missing? What did I hide with my `table { opacity: 0 }` rule there? How would you hide the whole document body instead?

Comment: You are right! I changed the css rule with new this one `@media screen { body { opacity: 0 } }` . Now the whole document body is hidden as I wanted to !

Comment: Great, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is working. 
 Please explain it more detailed.
I made a fiddle for you see that is working: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/76t0aLpq/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'print'
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.1.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.1.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tdbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Team Leader</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$235,500</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$324,050</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
          </tr>
        </tdbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: First of all thank for the your time! My goal is to only show data in the Print Preview! I was hoping to achieve this by setting the opacity of the main window in background to 0, so that the on the main window is not displayed ! I hope is clear

Comment: Here is the fiddle of what i have tried [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kanachrisi/n1kc9dyt/3/)